# In Jenkins-Pipeline how do I use sshPut to copy contents of folder, not folder itself?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

On my Jenkins server, I have a simple test pipeline to check into copying build data to a remote server. 
I'm using the SSH Pipeline Steps plugin.

My code is:

```
            stage('Remote SSH') {              
              steps {     
                sshRemove remote: remote, path: "/mnt/test"
                sshCommand remote: remote, command: "mkdir /mnt/test"                   

                writeFile file: './tst/abc.sh', text: 'ls -lrt'
                sshPut remote: remote, from: './tst/', into: '/mnt/test/.'
            }
```

The result is that in /mnt/test I have the created "tst" folder and it's contents.
What I wanted was just the contents of this tst folder to be transfered to the target.

How should I be formatting the sshPut step?

Comment: just a hunch, try using sshPut remote: remote, from: './tst/*.*', into: '/mnt/test/.'

Comment: I get an IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: /var/jenkins_home/jobs/copyTest/workspace/tst/*.* does not exist..

If run, "ls /var/jenkins_home/jobs/copyTest/workspace/tst/*.*" on the server it finds abc.sh. 

So it feels like a Java issue there.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at source-code and reading a bit about copy commands in Java it seems like this is just the way the filecopy operations work in Java. 
That one would have to iterate through the directory contents to do it another way.

Since I'm creating the source folder (even in my real build example), it seems that the best option is just to rename the folder before the move:

```
  sshRemove remote: remote, path: "/mnt/test"
  writeFile file: './tst/abc.sh', text: 'ls -lrt'
  sh "mv ./tst ./test"
  sshPut remote: remote, from: './test/.', into: '/mnt/'
```

I'd happily listen if someone has another solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue about this very use case on Jenkins'Jira https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-58778

I would expect the following to work but it apparently does not:

```
remote.fileTransfer = 'SCP'
sshPut remote: remote, from: './tst/*', into: '/mnt/test/'
```

Another way could be to do one sshCommand more after sshPut to 'mv' the files as you please

Usually I Go to `https://<myJenkins>/pipeline-syntax` and use the step builder. A shame it's not working for sshPut

Comment: In the Snippet Generator SSHPut just says "This is a special step. No snippet generation available" - is there another place I should look there?

Comment: Thanks for updating. The form you suggested ('./tst/*') produces an error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: /var/jenkins_home/jobs/copyTest/workspace/tst/* does not exist. 
Whereas './tst/." works, but copies the folder.

Comment: could you try to set the remote property fileTransfer to SCP? https://github.com/jenkinsci/ssh-steps-plugin/blob/master/README.adoc#configuration

Comment: Same result. 
I think this might not be possible.

Comment: indeed it might not be possible in one go. Actually there is an issue on Jenkins, maybe you could interact with the maintainers there https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-58778